# Tomcat Security Constraints - Disable file access on an HTTPS web app

Tags: security, tomcat, https, constraints

First the background -

1. I have an up and running JSF 1.1.14 web project in Tomcat.
2. Tomcat is hosting the same on HTTPS (SSL already configured and running fine)

To implement 2. above, we have the below configuration in web-app's web.xml –

```
<!-- ======= TRANSPORT GUARANTEE CONSTRAINT Starts ======= -->
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>URL reserved for Acquisition application</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<http-method>POST</http-method>
<http-method>GET</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<!-- ======= TRANSPORT GUARANTEE CONSTRAINT Ends ======== -->
```

The above, I believe is the industry standard approach for Tomcat.

Issue is that we need to disable the *.xhtml access via the web-app, and continue using HTTPS for the entire web app.

In an ideal environment, this is easily achievable using the below snippet…again in the web.xml file –

```
<!-- ======= Direct .xhtml access constraint - Starts ======= -->
<security-constraint>
<display-name>Restrict direct access to XHTML files</display-name>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>XHTML files</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
<!-- ======= Direct .xhtml access constraint - Ends ======= -->
```

Issue is, even after using the above, I am able to see the source of the *.xhtml files using the web-app URL.

The situation is perfect when HTTPS security-constraint is removed. My gut feel is that the HTTPS security constraint is over-riding the file access constraint.

I have searched high and low but am yet to find anything which works with both of these in tow.

Please help find something which works in disabling file access on a HTTPS web app.

Thanks.

Ckhurana

Comment: Hi Guys, anyone care to suggest any tips for this?

Comment: Are you using a web server (such as Apache httpd) in front of Tomcat, or is Tomcat serving all traffic?

Comment: Hi Christopher, no only Tomcat is running. All requests are catered and responded by Tomcat itself.

Comment: Seems strange...5 days and no-one cares to suggest any tips for this? Please people, some one who has done this? Care to reply?

Comment: Build a minimal test case WAR and post it somewhere like pastebin. I'll take a look. It's possible there is a bug in Tomcat, but it's not likely.